# How to open an existing entity form using JavaScript in CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4

If a custom ribbon button is clicked, is it possible to open an existing entity form using JavaScript or is there some other ways to open the existing form (e.g. campaign form)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```jscript
function PopNewCase() { 
     Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("incident", "GUID_OF_EXISTING_CASE"); 
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this function is only available when Rollup 8 or later is in use. [Xrm.Utility Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602956.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can, check this link. This explains the JavaScript part.
http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdevelopment/thread/de870f82-a4e0-49fa-abfd-06918098c86e
You need to pass entity type and record's guid into the url.

And here explains how to call a JavaScript function on ribbon button click,
http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2010/11/04/using-javascript-in-a-custom-button-in-crm-2011/

Using Visual Ribbon Editor might make things a bit easier.
http://crmvisualribbonedit.codeplex.com/

---

**edit:
Example from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328483.aspx**

```
window.open("/main.aspx?etn=account&pagetype=entityrecord&id=%7B91330924-802A-4B0D-A900-34FD9D790829%7D");
```

replace "account" with the entity type you want, and replace "7B91330924-802A-4B0D-A900-34FD9D790829" with the guid of the record you want.

Might use a function like this

```
function OpenRecord(entityName, recordId)
{
    window.open("/main.aspx?etn=" + entityName + "&pagetype=entityrecord&id=%7B" + recordId + "%7D");
}
```

Comment: thanks Dav , but i need to open a Campaign Form on button click... how to do this...

Comment: i tried

function PopNewCase() {
    Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("incident")
}
but its opening an new Case form.